# How can I require a Moose Attribute with an interface?

Tags: perl, interface, moose, role

You can do

```
use Moose::Role;
requires 'method';
```

I see in the [Moose::Spec::Role](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aRole) that I can also require Attributes, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The exact same syntax.  A Moose attribute provides an accessor method.  From the actual [CPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0603/lib/Moose/Role.pm#EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS):

"requires (@method_names)
Roles can require that certain methods are implemented by any class which does the role.

Note that attribute accessors also count as methods for the purposes of satisfying the requirements of a role."

Comment: that's not helpful if I need the method to return an object to delegate to. Also it seems to me that requiring an accessor isn't actually different from requiring a method. I suspect you may be correct though that this is the actual full functionality.

Comment: fair enough, but the documentation for M:Spec:Role clearly states that it is incomplete.  As far as I can read in the source, required Attributes--in a way that allows mandating the type--isn't yet supported.

Comment: to be a bit philosophical: the Moose system can be useful for simulating compile time debugging, but Perl is dynamic at heart, not static.  From a software engineering standpoint, Moose Roles are most useful for implementing aspect-oriented/cross-cutting/whateveryourpreferred buzzword concerns, not dressing up Perl as a static language.  The sanity check that `requires` provides is sufficient for attributes without enforcing type, or you should be using a different language.

Comment: I don't know that I really care about strictly enforcing type.. but quite simply this would fail if it can't delegate. I could do something like `requires_attribute name => ( isa => Object, does => role )` or `can => method` and that other role have the requires that I need. Big difference between enforcing type and knowing I'm going to delegate to a method.

Comment: weeeeell, enforcing type vs enforcing duck type...seems like potayto, potahto to me.  Is your concern to do with someone else implementing the contract or with debugging yourself?